# How to prevent directly accessing a php file from its parent file?

Tags: php

I have a php file in www.example.com/somefile.php that includes a file in another directory www.example.com/directory/someotherfile.php. How can I prevent someone from accessing someotherfile.php directly?

Answer (score 0):

Using .htaccess files.

More info: http://htaccess-guide.com/

Using .htaccess files you can either deny access to anyone *except* from a certain IP range (e.g. for Intranet) or require a password.

For example password required except from internal IP range:

```
AuthName "Staff only, please enter password"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /path/outside/of/var/www/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
Order allow,deny
Allow from 192.168.0.
satisfy any
```

Make sure your version of Apache2 supports .htaccess files and check the configuration.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not what I'm looking for. I need to prevent from accessing the page directly and instead go through somefile.php to access someotherfile.php. Also .htaccess is to much effort to manage. I don't want passwords.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put the file outside of the hosted space so www.example.com/somefile.php (on eg /home/usr/public_html/somefile.php) includes for example /home/usr/includes/someotherfile.php. If this is not possible a variation on the above .htaccess solution is possible where you place the include files in a directory that nobody may access. It will still be possible for your php file to include it. You won't need to setup passwords, just block all requests to the directory.

Comment: How can that be done with .htaccess without password protection?

Comment: either
order deny,allow
deny from all
or
Require all denied
depending on the apache version